# Neo4J Javascript drivers can't pass the read data to object

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I have to admit I feel a bit lost as I'm not an expert javascript programmer.

I want to query my neo4j db in order to store in a variable a json-like structure of my data coming from a simple query like

```
MATCH (a:VarA)-->(b:VarB) RETURN a.var1 as one, a.var2 as two, b.var3 as three, b.var4 as four;
```

So I wrote some simple code like:

```
var driver = neo4j.driver(
        'BOLT PATH',
        neo4j.auth.basic('MYUSER', 'MYPASS'),
        { disableLosslessIntegers: true }
    );
var session = driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.WRITE });

session
    .run("MYCYPHERQUERY")
    .then(r => {
        results = r.records.map(d => d.toObject());
        data = JSON.stringify(results);
        session.close();
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        results = [];
        console.log(error);
    })
```

But, I guess I'm stuck in this async function, as if I add

console.log(data);

after the code, it returns an empty array, while the one in the .then block is triggered after and returns the proper json file.

However this blocks me as I want to pass this object to the next function, which doesn't work.

How can I add to this an option to wait for the results to be stored in data variable before proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Result.then](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/result.js~Result.html#instance-method-then) method returns a Javascript [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which you should learn about.

Probably the simplest way to (asynchronously) pass the `results` (or an error) to your `next()` function (which you will have to write) is: return `results` from your existing `then`, and chain another `then` call after the existing one:

```
session
  .run("MYCYPHERQUERY")
  .then(r => {
    const results = r.records.map(d => d.toObject()); // results can be local
    data = JSON.stringify(results);
    session.close();
    console.log(data);
    return results;
  })
  .then(r => {
    next(null, r);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  })
```

In above example, `next()` takes an error (or `null`) as the first parameter, and the results (or `undefined`) as the second parameter.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this helps me a lot, I'm giving a read to the documentation you posted about promises.
the next function is defined by me or part of the drivers?
asking because I'm getting an error "next is undefined"

Comment: `next` is a function you have to write. I modified my answer to make that clearer. I cleverly called the function "next" because your question said "I want to pass this object to the next function". :-)

Comment: Actually, it would be even simpler to just call `next(null, results)` at the bottom of the first `then` method (rather than returning `result`), in which case you would not even need the second `then` invocation. But then you'd have little excuse to study the `promise` mechanism, which you should really know about anyway if you want to be good at javascript...